# Why has the category of all discrete $G$-modules not enough projectives when $G$ is profinite?

Tags: modules, galois-cohomology

I found [this article](http://math.uga.edu/%7Eturkelli/Introduction%20to%20Galois%20Cohomology.pdf) about Galois Cohomology.

In it, it says that, when $G$ is a profinite group and $\mathbf{C}_G$ is the category of all discrete $G$-modules, $\mathbf{C}_G$ doesn't have enough projectives. He explains this by saying that $\mathbb{Z}G$ is not in $\mathbf{C}_G$ (which I understand because there isn't an open subgroup $U$ of $G$ that fixes $e_1$, the 1 in $\mathbb{Z}G$), so no free module over $\mathbb{Z}G$ is in $\mathbf{C}_G$. Therefore, he concludes that $\mathbf{C}_G$ doesn't contain enough projectives. Why is that ?

<sup>1</sup>Seyfi Türkell: *Galois cohomology* - [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100612034538/http://math.uga.edu/%7Eturkelli/Introduction%20to%20Galois%20Cohomology.pdf)